# Auto Dial a phone number from web application on mobile browser [Without going to dialpad]

Tags: javascript, html, web, mobile

i want to create a link or something on which if a user clicks on "Call" button, it'll directly dial the call rather than taking it to dialer-pad. Now but in mobile browsers, clicking on such link will open the dialer-pad, is there any way to directly call from web browser [Mobile]

Asked a question on mobile browser capability, and expecting a right response based on that.

Comment: Didn't try but maybe just using the `tel://` [URI for telephone numbers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3966) might work.

Comment: If a web page could dial a (potentially expensive) phone number without further user interaction, that would be huge security issue.